# How to make custom validation annotation to check if object already exist?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator

i am using spring and hibernate validation, and i want to make a custom annotation that checks if a username already exists in the database or not, can anyone please provide me with examples for such thing ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of what you want (the check if email exists in database)

http://nonrepeatable.blogspot.com/2010/05/creating-custom-jsr-303-constraint.html

Comment: when i tried this example i found that it contains lots of syntax errors, is there's any other complete correct example.